# How to get the isAdmin field in FireStore and check if it's true or false in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Hello everyone I'm making an application with flutter which has different views for normal users admins and unauthenticated users, but the logic that I'm going for isn't working and I don't know why.

P.S here I'm only trying to differentiate between admins and normal users.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
Future<bool> isAdmin() async {
    final currentUserUid = _firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid;
    //What I'm trying to do here is get my isAdmin field which is created when a user is created
    final DocumentSnapshot db = await 
          databaseReference.collection('users').doc(currentUserUid).get();
    return db.data().containsKey('isAdmin');
  }
```

This is how I'm trying to implement it

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../../screens/auth/admin/admin_tab_bar_screen.dart';
import '../../screens/auth/user_tab_bar_screen.dart';
import '../../providers/auth.dart';

class AuthTabBarScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = 'auth-tab-bar-view';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final checkUserRole = Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).isAdmin();

    // Here I want to check the Value I'm returning if its true
    if(checkUserRole == true){
      return AdminTabBarScreen();
    } else {
      return UserTabBarScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FutureBuilder` which waits for a future (`isAdmin()` in your case) before building. `snapshot.data` is the value of the `future`.

```
class AuthTabBarScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = 'auth-tab-bar-view';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).isAdmin(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData
          ? snapshot.data // if isAdmin() is true
              ? AdminTabBarScreen() // return Admin
              : UserTabBarScreen() // else if false, return UserTab
          : Loading(), // while you're waiting for the data, show some kind of loading indicator
    );
  }
}
```

`isAdmin()` returns `Future<bool>` which is a future value so when you compare `Future<bool>` and `bool`, you will receive an equality error because one is a `Future` and the other is a `bool`. Using `FutureBuilder()`, your app waits for `Provider.of<Auth>...isAdmin()` to return a value or `snapshot`. A `snapshot` is an async value of your future so calling `snapshot.data` is the same as `await Provider.of<Auth>...isAdmin()` which is why `snapshot.data` returns a `bool` and not a `Future<bool>`. It might be helpful to understand how futures, async, await work [documentation](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await).

Comment: it works, but I don't understand how though, can you please explain from the builder and below how it works and how it checks if the isAdmin value is true or false.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now after I checked the documentation in the flutter SDK and now from the link you provided as well.

Answer (score 2):

i didn't test it but this will probably work for you.
basically `db.data()` is a map so, if you search your key you will get what you want
like that

```
Future<bool> isAdmin() async {
    final currentUserUid = _firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid;
    final DocumentSnapshot db = await 
          databaseReference.collection('users').doc(currentUserUid).get();
    return db.data()['isAdmin'];
  }
```

Comment: Well for getting the value it worked, but how do I use the value that I get from the isAdmin method in the second code, because when I try as I've tried in the second code the AuthTabBarScreen it doesn't work because it says "Equality operator `==` invocation with references of unrelated types.".??

Comment: @NiiTii isAdmin() returns a future so you need to add 'await' in front of Provider.of<> and make it an async function. take it out of the build() method too

Comment: @Karen I made a new function outside of the build method " Future<bool> isUserAdmin() async{return await Provider.of<>...} ", and tried to check the method on the if statement, but it still doesn't work it keeps saying " Equality operator == invocation with references of unrelated types. ". What do I do?

Comment: @NiiTii i posted an answer with a different approach