# Flutter and Firebase admin and normal user signin

Tags: firebase, flutter

hello i am new to flutter and firebase and i have a field in the user document that is called admin and it's a boolean , i want to check this boolean in the sign in functionality . what i came up so far is this :

```
onPressed: () async {
  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
    if (!await user.signIn(_email.text, _password.text)) {
      toast("Signin Faild");
    } else {
      if(await _firestore.collection('users').doc(_auth.currentUser.uid).get().)
        changeScreenReplacement(context, HomePage());
      toast("Signedin successfully");
    }
  }
},
```

i don't know what to do in this part :
`if(await _firestore.collection('users').doc(_auth.currentUser.uid).get().)`

i want here to check the field if it's equal to true or false how can i do this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the isAdmin field in FireStore and check if it's true or false in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66232768/how-to-get-the-isadmin-field-in-firestore-and-check-if-its-true-or-false-in-flu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After awaiting for *get()* call you will have a [DocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html) instance, from which you can read the data.

Calling *get()* on [DocumentReference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html) always return *DocumentSnapshot* instance, even if document doesn't exist in the database. So you probably also need to check it.

Also calling data() on *DocumentSnapshot* will return null if such document not exist in database.

So this can be written at least in two ways.

**With explicitly check if document exist in database.**

```dart
final userSnapshot = await _firestore.collection('users').doc(_auth.currentUser.uid).get();

if(userSnapshot.exists) {
  if(userSnapshot.data()['admin'] == true) {
    toast('User is admin');
  } else {
    toast('User not admin');
  }
} else {
  toast('User document not exist in database');
}
```

Or in **short way and just ignoring fact that user document can be not exist.**

```dart
final userSnapshot = await _firestore.collection('users').doc(_auth.currentUser.uid).get();
if(((await _firestore.collection('users').doc(_auth.currentUser.uid).get()).data() ?? const {})['admin'] == true) {
  toast('User is admin');
} else {
  toast('User not admin or user document not exist');
}
```